# how to raise a framebox

Tags: framed, vertical

I want the two lower boxes to butt up directly against (in fact overlap exactly) with the upper box.
I tried `\raisebox` but this didn't do the right thing.
`\offinterlineskip` *almost* does the right job, but I would like the upper border of the lower box to sit on top of the lower border of the upper box.
I tried a negative `vspace` but this did nothing.

the MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{0ex}
\begin{document}
\huge
\fboxsep=0pt
\fboxrule=0.5pt
% \vspace*{-1pt}
% \offinterlineskip
\framebox{\parbox[b][2cm][c]{5cm}{\hfill6\hspace*{\fill}}}\\
\framebox{\parbox[b][2cm][c]{\dimexpr(2.5cm-\fboxrule)\relax}{\hfill4\hspace*{\fill}}}%
\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
\framebox{\parbox[b][2cm][c]{\dimexpr(2.5cm)\relax}{\hfill2\hspace*{\fill}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To overlap, use \lineskip=-0.5pt, but put it in a group so that it will revert to normal when done.

Comment: I tried this, but doesn't raise the box. It seems not to make any difference.

Comment: Are you using \offinterlineskip?  That turns off \lineskip.

Comment: no, i'm not using \offinterlineskip. just inserted \lineskip=-0.5pt within group containing the \frameboxes

Comment: Oops! For some reason it has to be set globally.  Probably because the code which uses it is higher that the code which sets it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't a stack be easier?  That way, all the `\parskip`/`\vspace`/`interlineskip` stuff is moot.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\huge
\fboxsep=0pt
\fboxrule=0.5pt
\stackunder[-\fboxrule]{%
  \framebox{\parbox[b][2cm][c]{5cm}{\hfill6\hspace*{\fill}}}%
}{%
  \framebox{\parbox[b][2cm][c]{\dimexpr(2.5cm-\fboxrule)\relax}{\hfill4\hspace*{\fill}}}%
  \hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \framebox{\parbox[b][2cm][c]{\dimexpr(2.5cm)\relax}{\hfill2\hspace*{\fill}}}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had never heard of this package before.  But it does the trick and more.

Comment: @Tim Thanks.  And if you need to do stacks that are tabbed, look up the `tabstackengine` package that extends it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `minipage` to save and restore `\lineskip`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{0ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\huge
\fboxsep=0pt
\fboxrule=0.5pt
\lineskip=-0.5pt
% \vspace*{-1pt}
% \offinterlineskip
\framebox{\parbox[b][2cm][c]{5cm}{\hfill6\hspace*{\fill}}}\\
\framebox{\parbox[b][2cm][c]{\dimexpr(2.5cm-\fboxrule)\relax}{\hfill4\hspace*{\fill}}}%
\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
\framebox{\parbox[b][2cm][c]{\dimexpr(2.5cm)\relax}{\hfill2\hspace*{\fill}}}%
\end{minipage}
\the\lineskip
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]